# Display state header only once, and still display all addresses in that state

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm looking for a way to display:

```
<h1>State1</h1>

<h2>City1</h2>
<p>Address1</p>


***if next address is in the same state:*

<h2>City2</h2>
<p>Address2</p>

<hr>

**if next address is NOT in the same state

<h1>State2</h1>

<h2>City3</h2>
<p>Address3</p>
```

I'm using:

```
<?php    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM places";
    $select_all_places = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
    $p_state = $row['p_state'];
    $p_city = $row['p_city'];
    $p_address = $row['p_address'];

    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $p_state ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $p_city ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $p_address ?></p>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: inside your while, check if the state is different to the previous member, add a conditional on rendering the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code here.  I added some semicolons on your echo statements and added the query variable into the mysqli_fetch_assoc method for you.  I added some comments as well to help you understand what I have done here.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM places";
$select_all_places = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

// This will be the state we are currently on. Start it as null.
$current_state = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_places)){
    $p_state = $row['p_state'];
    $p_city = $row['p_city'];
    $p_address = $row['p_address'];

?>
    <!-- Check if variable state is equal to current row's state. -->
    <?php if($current_state != $p_state): ?>

        <!-- Echo state if they aren't equal  -->
        <h1><?php echo $p_state; ?></h1>

        <!-- Assign new current state -->
        <?php $current_state = $p_state; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h2><?php echo $p_city; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $p_address; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm using this answer with bootstrap, and I'm having a problem to keep the address that are in the same state, in the same row, if you know how, can you please let me know? I might have to create another question I guess...

Comment: I would ask another question for that. It would be hard for me to help without being able to see the full code.